# When proving a partial order relation is a total order do we have assume both elements are distinct?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

Consider the "divides" relation on the set $A=\lbrace 1,2,2^2,.\;.\;.,2^n\rbrace$, where $n$ is a non-negative integer. Prove that this relation is a total order on $A$.
First we prove $A$ is a partial ordered set.

Reflexitivity: It is easy to see that $a \mid a$ where $a \in A$ therefore the divides relation is reflexive on $A$.

Anti-Symmetric: If $a \mid a^{*} \wedge a* \mid a \implies a=a$ where $a,a^{*} \in A$. This is true since $a=a^{*}k_1$ and $a^{*}=ak_2$ then $a=ak_1k_2 \implies k_1=k_2=1 \wedge a=a$ Therefore the divides relation is anti-symmetric on $A$

Transitivity: If $(a\mid b\; \wedge b \mid c) \implies a \mid c$ where $a,b,c \in A$ We have by the definition of divisibility $b=ak_1$ and $c=bk_2$ By substitution we get $c=ak_1k_2 \implies a \mid c$ Therefore the divides relation is Transitive on $A$\ \

Lastly we need to show that for any two elements $a,b \in A$ either $a \mid b$ or $b \mid a$ This is true by the definition of divisibility assuming that $a \neq b$ Therefore we conclude that the "divides" relation is a total order on $A$.

Is it safe to assume that $a \neq b$ in this case?

Comment: If $a=b$ you have reflexivity at your disposal, so yes.

Comment: but why does it matter? what does reflexivity have to do with the definition of a total order

Comment: If you want to show that $a|b \vee b|a \quad \forall\ a,b$ and know $a|a \quad \forall\ a$, you already have
$$a|b \vee b|a \qquad \forall\ a=b$$
so you only need a (new) proof for $a\neq b$.

Comment: Oh I see thanks

Comment: yes, some more characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For totality you want to show that
$$a|b \vee b|a \qquad \forall\ a,b\in A$$
However since you have shown that $|$ is a partial order, you can use it's reflexivity property to obtain
$$\begin{align*}
a|a & \qquad \forall\ a,b\in A\\
\Leftrightarrow a|b \vee b|a & \qquad \forall\ a,b\in A, a=b
\end{align*}$$
Thus the only remaining cases for totality are those with $a\neq b$, which justifies your assumption.